# Java Как отправить запрос на сервер

Tags: java, tomcat

Сделал на томкате скрипт что, если с браузера зайти на `http://localhost:8080/helloservlet/hello`, то мне в вк отправится hello в личные сообщения. Как сделать запрос не из браузера, а из java?

пытался таким способом, но не работает

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String query = "http://localhost:8080/helloservlet/hello";

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(query).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Что я хочу: чтоб я запустил код java -> отправился запрос на сервер -> сработал срикпт на сервере -> отправился Hello мне в лс в вк

Comment: У вас сервер точно на той же самой машине и адрес нормально открывается?

Comment: @Komdosh да, сервер на той же машине. Если открывать с браузера вручную, то все нормально и все работает

Comment: @Komdosh может надо параметры передавать? типо user-agent и т.д.

Comment: Вообще ему должно быть всё равно, попробуйте сначала curl дёрнуть, может проблема в сервере

Comment: @Komdosh короче я решил проверить нормально ли соедин или нет и решил вывести в консоль содержимое страницы (там слово "hello" выводится просто для теста) и когда я написал вывод в консоль и запустил, мне пришло нужное мне сообщение в вк. Как это вообще работает?

Comment: а, блин, сейчас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код не отправляет запрос. Вам необходимо начать считывать ответ:

```java
try (Scanner scanner =
             new Scanner(
                     new BufferedInputStream(
                             httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                     )
             )
) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

или хотя бы статус:

```java
httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()
```

Comment: вот секунду назад сам до этого дошел)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связана с операцией `openConnection`, она только создаёт соединение как объект, но при этом не отправляет запрос, для самого запроса необходимо, как написано в ответе ранее, вызвать функцию `getInputStream()` или `getResponseCode()`